# Google spreadsheets: Find max value for a name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have spreadsheet with 2 columns - names and values, say:

- John  2
- Doe   8
- Mary 17
- John  5
- Bill 12
- Mary  6
- John  3

What formula can I use to find the maximum value for each name? (E.g. in column C in each row with John would be 5, with Mary - 17, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion simplest by far but offering much more than just what you ask is a pivot table:

[image: WA103533 example]

You could though try:

```
=query(I:J,"select I, max(J) group by I")
```